# Search view nested arrays

Tags: search, view, couchdb

I've got race participant data in some documents, organized by race stage, runner position, and the time the runner passed through the stage.

I need to find a particular bib (?key=357) and grab the last time it went through a stage (doc.bib_data[i].time), which stage it was (id) and the position (i).

If I specify a particular bib_data array index, I get results, but if I loop through the bib_data, I don't get any results, even if I don't filter for anything.

VIEW with a specific index, to show what the document data looks like:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.bib_data[2].bib,doc.bib_data[2].time);
}
```

RESULT:

```
{
 "id": "007",
 "key": "357",
 "value": "1910:38",
 "doc": {
  "_id": "007",
  "_rev": "4-bdce057c8ad2ce975b9ffca9eb9dfd82",
  "ew_ham": "KM6WKA",
  "stage_ew_ham": "KK6DA",
  "bib_data": {
   "1": {
    "bib": "45",
    "time": "1910:35"
   },
   "2": {
    "bib": "357",
    "time": "1910:38"
   },
   "3": {
    "bib": "22",
    "time": "1910:40"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

How do I get results ONLY for "bib:357"?

I need to collect the stage, the position and the time, i.e. ["007","2","1910:38"]

```
   "2": {
    "bib": "357",
    "time": "1910:38"
   },
```

Here's my current QUERY:

```
http://[IP_ADDR]:5984/[DB_NAME]/_design/[DESIGN_DOC]/_view/[VIEW_NAME]?key=123
```

And my VIEW that attempts to loop through bib_data:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  for(i=0;i<doc.bib_data.length;i++) {
    if(doc.bib_data[i].bib) {
      emit( i, doc.bib_data[i].bib, doc.bib_data[i].time );
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view code

```js
function(doc, meta) {
  for (i = 0; i < doc.bib_data.length; i++) {
    if (doc.bib_data[i].bib) {
      emit(i, doc.bib_data[i].bib, doc.bib_data[i].time);
    }
  }
}
```

Is totally incorrect as it is an attempt to index iterate `bib_data` as if it were an array but *it's an object*.  So fix that first <sup>[1]</sup>:

```js
function (doc) {
  for (var key in doc.bib_data) {
    if (doc.bib_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var item = doc.bib_data[key];
      /* do something with the bib item. */
    }
  }
}
```

Now it's time to emit the data of interest.  It's not super clear what is desired from your post, but here's a start, noting I am emitting what appear to be numbers as numbers not strings:

```js
function (doc) {
  for (var key in doc.bib_data) {
    if (doc.bib_data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var item = doc.bib_data[key];
      if(item.bib) {
        emit([parseInt(item.bib), parseInt(key), item.time]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Given the doc you posted as the only doc in the database with design doc and view name as `bib` using cURL:

```
curl -G <url to db>/_design/bib/_view/bib
```

will return

> { "total_rows":3,"offset":0,"rows":[
>     {"id": "007", "key": [22,3,"1910:40"], "value": null},
>     {"id": "007", "key": [45,1,"1910:35"], "value": null},
>     {"id": "007", "key": [357,2,"1910:38"], "value": null}
>   ]}

Because the `bib` view is generating a complex key one must query<sup>[2]</sup> using `start_key` and `end_key`.  So to get view documents with a  `bib` of 357

```
 curl -G <url to db>/_design/bib/_view/bib -d "start_key=[357]" -d "end_key=[357,{}]"
```

will return

> {"total_rows":3,"offset":2,"rows":[
>   {"id":"007","key":[357,2,"1910:38"],"value":null}
>   ]}

I am not seeing much utility with incorporating the index/key - maybe you want this instead?

```js
emit([parseInt(item.bib), item.time], parseInt(key));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)
<sup>2</sup> [/{db}/_design/{ddoc}/_view/{view}](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html#get--db-_design-ddoc-_view-view)

Comment: Thank you, RamblinRose! You really cleared it up, for me.

Comment: To expand on my comment:

You cleared it up for me in that I'm working with an object, rather than an array, and in helping me to understand the couchdb syntax for getting at what I needed.

I'm a bit of an idiot for not seeing the object notation ...

In re: index/key: That's the Stage indicator. So ... 09m = 1 mile out from the Stage, 09k = 200 meters out and 009 = the Stage marker. I want to pull the most-recent entry in the doc to be able to see where the runner was last recorded.

Thanks, again.